# How do I remove an element from an array and move everything up a spot?

Tags: c++

I am trying to remove a name from this array and then have an empty spot at the last position of the array once removed. How do I do this? Here is what I tried below. It removes it, but doesnt move to the end.

```
const int array_size = 16;
string restaurants[array_size] = {"Texas Roadhouse","On The Border","Olive Garden","Panda       Express","Cracker Barrel","IHOP","Woohoo","Pei Wei","Mcdonalds","Denny's","Mrs. Fields","Subway","Dairy Queen","Burger King","Pizza Hut","Dominos"};
int current_size = 16;

cout << "Please enter the name of the Restaurant you would like to remove: ";
cin.ignore();
getline(cin, remove_restaurant);

remove(restaurants, restaurants_size, remove_restaurant);//function call

bool remove(string restaurants[], int& current_size, string name)//function to remove   array
{
    for (int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)//look at each name you want to remove
    {
        if ( restaurants[i] == name)
        {
        restaurants[i]=restaurants[i+1];
        current_size --;
        cout << "Restaurant removed successfully." << endl;
        return true;            
        }
    }
return false;
}
```

Comment: Use a list instead of an array.

Comment: Specifically, use a std::list from the STL

Comment: This is only marginally C++ (cout/cin & inline declarations).  Use the STL container as suggested to truly make it a C++ solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the remove-erase idiom, with `std::remove` and `std::fill`:

```
bool remove(string restaurants[], int& current_size, string name)//function to remove   array
{
    auto begin = std::begin(restaurants);
    auto end = std::next(begin, current_size);
    auto new_end = std::remove(begin, end, name);
    std::fill(new_end, end, {});
    current_size = std::distance(begin, new_end);
    if (new_end != end) {
        std::cout << "Restaurant removed successfully." << std::endl;
    }
    return new_end != end;
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you add the "removed successfully" message to this? Check for new_end != end? Also, is that {} an initializer list to fill with empty values? I would have simply used "", is that worse?

Comment: @Sarien ah, missed that side effect.  `""` is in principle less efficient, because the `std::string` constructor has to read from the empty string literal (although the compiler is likely to optimise it away).

Answer (score 2):

1. Create an array of the same size as the original
2. Begin iterating elements of the original array
3. If the current item in the array does not equal the item to remove, add it to the new array

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible way to amend your current solution. I agree with ott--, though, you should probably use a list instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < current_size; i++)//look at each name you want to remove
{
  if (restaurants[i] == name) {
    swap(restaurants[i], restaurants[current_size-1]);
    current_size --;
    cout << "Restaurant removed successfully." << endl;
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove), and [`std::vector::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// ...

vector<string> restaurants { ... };

string remove_restaurant;
getline(cin, remove_restaurant);

restaurants.erase
  (remove(restaurants.begin(), restaurants.end(), remove_restaurant));
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think you'd much rather use a `vector` or `list` for this, that's what it has been designed for. But if you want to go this way, you could for example write a `moveUp` method:

```
 void moveUp(int startIndex, int endIndex, string* array) {
     for (int ii = startIndex; ii < endIndex; ++ii) {
         array[ii] = array[ii + 1];
     }

     array[endIndex] = 0;
 }
```